# Using npm in visual studio 2017 without internet connection

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, npm, asp.net-core

I am new in angular js, recently I'm assigned to a project where I have to work with angular js with asp.net core 2.0. Now the problem I'm facing is that, the development pc doesn't have internet(company policy). How can I use npm in such situation? I've already installed node.js and npm in the system but visual studio can't seem to find node packages. I even tried to solve the problem by adding npm location to 
Projects and solutions->Web package management.
Still every time visual studio runs npm.CMD command and try to install packages from internet.If anyone can resolve this issue, would be greatly helpful.

Comment: are your packages hosted on an internal network?

Comment: `npm install http-server -g` would give you a zero-configuration command-line http server (how to install it offline, is beyond me)

Comment: somewhere you include online reference link in your project. kindly check that. it will work

Comment: packages are installed locally...not hosted on internal network. Packages might get hosted on server once requirement analysis done...and coding structure is developed by team leader @Marco

Comment: If you have no connection to a package repository online or on an internal network, then you are not able to install the dependencies. If you have a machine with a working solution, you could copy the complete solution from there using a flash drive or shared folder.

Comment: Tell your boss to stop stucking in programming 1990's. All modern software development requires an internet connection through at least a proxy. All package managers get their packages from internet (or some local repository which gets it earlier or on demand from internet). Maven, Gradle, npm, nuget, chocholately, composer.